# How to get an easy to compute representation defined by plot of involved function?

Tags: approximation

I am doing a windmill vortex sheet calculation where I have to guess its shape and then vorticity distribution and then make sure that the net flow is along the sheet. The problem is adjusting my assumed slope $yp[x]$ to the calculated flow slope which is smooth. My analytic correction functions to the assumed shape take hours to concoct but still have wobbly derivative= slope in cyan whereas I would do better to just adopt the current flow slope magenta which is much smoother, but very involved to calculate and of course dependent on the current $y[x]$.*[image: emphasized text]* I will need to differentiate this new $y'[x]$ at $x=0$, and integrate it from $0$ to $x$ and renormalise to have the correct value as x gets very large.

How do I form such an approximating slope function from  from this plot command, please? Thank you Ulrich for command to get a list of plot points.. How do I form an interpolating function from this list, please?

```
pic = Plot[  2*V[x]/U[x] , {x, 0, 6}];
pts = Cases[pic, Line[p_] :> p, -1][[1]]

(** pts = {{0.0418311, 1.05753}, {0.0421502, 1.05522}, {0.043392, 1.04643}, {0.0458757, 1.02957}, {0.0508431, 0.998504}, {0.0511536, 0.996669}, {0.051464, 0.994846}, {0.052085, 0.991235}, {0.0533268, 0.984148}, {0.0558105, 0.970492}, {0.0607779, 0.945057},      {0.0610823,0.943573}, {0.0613866, 0.942097}, {0.0619954, 0.939171}, {0.0632129, 0.933411}, {0.0656478, 0.922254},      {0.0705178,0.901272}, {0.0708221, 0.900015}, {0.0711265, 0.898765}, {0.0717353, 0.896282}, {0.0729527, 0.891387}, {0.0753877,0.88187}, {0.0802576, 0.863853}, {0.0805878, 0.862677}, { 0.080918, 0.861507}, {0.0815783, 0.859183}, {0.082899, 0.8546}, {0.0855404, 0.845683}, {0.0908231, 0.828772}, {0.101388, 0.798165}, {0.101697, 0.79733}, {0.102005, 0.796497}, {0.102621, 0.794841}, {0.103854, 0.791563}, {0.106319, 0.785144}, {0.111249, 0.772819}, {0.121109, 0.750011}, {0.121443, 0.749278}, {0.121777, 0.748547}, {0.122445, 0.747092}, {0.123781, 0.744211}, {0.126452, 0.738559}, {0.131795, 0.727671}, {0.142481, 0.707402}, {0.142809, 0.706809}, {0.143137, 0.706218}, {0.143792, 0.705041}, {0.145104, 0.702705}, {0.147726, 0.69811}, {0.152972, 0.689206}, {0.163463, 0.672452}, {0.183035, 0.644411}, {0.204257, 0.617828}, {0.22407, 0.595859}, {0.243493, 0.576488}, {0.264567, 0.557472}, {0.284231, 0.541304}, {0.305546, 0.525233}, {0.326471, 0.510714}, {0.345986, 0.498146}, {0.367151, 0.48544}, {0.386907, 0.474348}, {0.408314, 0.463069}, {0.429331, 0.452663}, {0.448938, 0.44349}, {0.470196, 0.434071}, {0.490044, 0.425725}, {0.509502, 0.417927}, {0.530611, 0.40986}, {0.55031, 0.402672}, {0.57166, 0.395221}, {0.59262, 0.388225}, {0.61217, 0.381963}, {0.633371, 0.375438}, {0.653162, 0.369581}, {0.672563, 0.364044}, {0.693616, 0.358251}, {0.713258, 0.353035}, {0.734551, 0.347574}, {0.754434, 0.342646}, {0.773927, 0.337967}, {0.795071, 0.333052}, {0.814805, 0.328608}, {0.83619, 0.323939}, {0.857186, 0.319497}, {0.876771, 0.315472}, {0.898007, 0.311233}, {0.917833, 0.307387}, {0.93727, 0.303715}, {0.958357, 0.299839}, {0.978034, 0.296317}, {0.978378, 0.296256}, {0.978721, 0.296196}, {0.979407, 0.296074}, {0.98078, 0.295832}, {0.983526, 0.29535}, {0.989017, 0.29439}, {0.98936, 0.29433}, {0.989704, 0.29427}, {0.99039, 0.294151}, {0.991763, 0.293912}, {0.994509, 0.293436}, {0.994852, 0.293377}, {0.995195, 0.293317}, {0.995881, 0.293199}, {0.997254, 0.292962}, {0.997597, 0.292903}, {0.997941, 0.292844}, {0.998627, 0.292725}, {0.99897, 0.292666}, {0.999314, 0.292607}, {0.999657, 0.292548}, {1., 0.292489}}; **)

ifun=Interpolation[pts];
```

Comment: Definitions of functions inside `Plot` are missing but even if you provide the definitions I still do not understand what you are asking.

Comment: Could you please provide the plotted cyan points  `2*V[x]/U[x]` . You might take them from a extra plot  `pic=Plot[  2*V[x]/U[x] , {x, 0, 6}]; pts=Cases[pic, Line[p_] :> p, -1][[1]]`

Comment: . Outputs the points.Thanks So then need an interpolating function to them.  list is too long to paste here, and when try to put in question says its is code.

Comment: You have not provided a minimum working example. No definitions for any of your functions.

Comment: @Edmund Ok I finally got the points added to the question which is now how to form an interpolating function?

Comment: `Interpolation[data]`.

Comment: @simon Does knowledge of  `ifun` answer your question? Or is "... I will need to differentiate this new $y'[x]$ at $x=0$, and integrate it from $0$ to $x$ and renormalise to have the correct value as x gets very large." still open issue?